# Java 8 abstract class with Interface having default method

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, java-8, default-method

I have an interface `A` with a default method `printme()`, same method I am having in an abstract class `B`. If I am extending abstract class `B` with a `TestClass` and implementing interface `A`, `printme()` method is not visible in `TestClass`.
Below is code:

```
interface A {

    default void printme() {
        System.out.println("Interface A");
    }
}

abstract class B {
    public void printme() {
        System.out.println("Abstract Class B");
    }
}

public class TestDefaultMethod extends B implements A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestDefaultMethod td = new TestDefaultMethod();
        td.printme(); //from Interface A
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand how and why I am not able to access method from Abstract  class.

Comment: In what sense aren't you able to access the method from the abstract class?  (It's the interface method I wouldn't expect you to be able to access.)

Comment: I ran this code and got "Abstract Class B".

Comment: See, If you do "td.printme()" the printme() method is visible from Interface A , but I am unable to understand why I can not access method "printme()" which is given in Abstract class B

Comment: @Eran , thats correct at run time you td.printme() is executing method from Abrstact class but at Compile time its picking method from interface A.
If you are using any editor like eclipse , you can do td.pri... and in help suggestion given by eclipse , you see printme() method is from interface A.

Comment: And if you hit F2 on the method call in Eclipse, you'll see `void B.printme()`. So your problem is not "compile time", but Eclipse auto-completion, which has *nothing* to do with compile-time. It seems that auto-completion eliminated the wrong "duplicate" of the method. File a bug with Eclipse.

Comment: Are you using NetBeans?  This works fine for me in Eclipse.  I've seen several problems recently regarding NetBeans' compiler having trouble with overloading resolution.

Comment: @Andreas  You are correct .now I am confused ,why not default method given in interface A is being called ,Please explain how its working

Comment: The default would be used only if there was no other implementation further down the inheritance tree (below A). Since `B#printme()` exists, it is used.

Comment: @Andreas: thanks for hinting to the Eclipse issue.